# Geographic Midpoint between two coordinates

Tags: c#, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have been using the Moveable-Type website to aid me in some Geocoordinate calcuations and it's been very useful, however, I have a bug in my calculation of the mid-point between two coordinates.  My result is close to the expected, but not close enough:

```
posA = {47.64570362, -122.14073746}
posB = {47.64316917, -122.14032175}
```

expected result (taken from the movable type calculator) = 47°38′40″N, 122°08′26″W = `{47.644444, -122.140556}` my result: `{49.6054801645915, -122.14052959995759}`

Here is my code:

```
private Geocoordinate MidPoint(Geocoordinate posA, Geocoordinate posB)
{
   Geocoordinate midPoint = new Geocoordinate();

   double dLon = DegreesToRadians(posB.Longitude - posA.Longitude);
   double Bx = Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(posB.Latitude)) * Math.Cos(dLon);
   double By = Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(posB.Latitude)) * Math.Sin(dLon);

   midPoint.Latitude = RadiansToDegrees(Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(posA.Latitude)) + Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(posB.Latitude)), 
                Math.Sqrt((Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(posA.Latitude)) + Bx) * (Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(posA.Latitude))) + Bx) + By * By));

   midPoint.Longitude = posA.Longitude + RadiansToDegrees(Math.Atan2(By, Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(posA.Latitude)) + Bx));

   return midPoint;
}
```

I've got a couple of private methods to do the conversion between Degrees and Radians and back. 
E.g.

```
private double DegreeToRadian(double angle)
{
   return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;
}
```

I can't work out why my results are off by a couple of degrees on the Lat value.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Off my **whole** degrees (you expect `34.8954` but get `29.8954`) or **approximate** (you expect `34.8954` but get `29.7836`)?

Comment: i'm not quite sure if you're considering the earth's surface as a simple sphere or an ellipsoidal sphere. the last time i worked w/ Lambert's law [using a Java implementation] and it seemed to work accurately.

Comment: Thanks.  It is out by 2 degrees on the lat, and the lon is pretty much spot on.  I'm using the formula for Mid-point calculation on this website, translated into C# http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: I hate trig... Thank you for this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You placed some parentheses wrong. I marked the place in the code.

```
private Geocoordinate MidPoint(Geocoordinate posA, Geocoordinate posB)
{
   Geocoordinate midPoint = new Geocoordinate();

   double dLon = DegreesToRadians(posB.Longitude - posA.Longitude);
   double Bx = Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(posB.Latitude)) * Math.Cos(dLon);
   double By = Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(posB.Latitude)) * Math.Sin(dLon);

   midPoint.Latitude = RadiansToDegrees(Math.Atan2(
                Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(posA.Latitude)) + Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(posB.Latitude)),
                Math.Sqrt(
                    (Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(posA.Latitude)) + Bx) *
                    (Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(posA.Latitude)) + Bx) + By * By))); 
                 // (Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(posA.Latitude))) + Bx) + By * By)); // Your Code

   midPoint.Longitude = posA.Longitude + RadiansToDegrees(Math.Atan2(By, Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(posA.Latitude)) + Bx));

   return midPoint;
}
```

Comment: :( I was just about to post this. Good catch.

Comment: Thank you!!! I thought it would be something simple, I don't know how I missed that! You're a star!

Answer (score 0):

Some methods (eg WGS84 conventions) include oblateness of the earth. ([at least that's what it says here](http://fit.c2.com/wiki.cgi?GeoCoordinate))