# MKMapView Doesn't Show Whole World At Once

Tags: ios, mapkit, zooming

I'm working on an application that tracks movement in Swift, for traveling from point A: `locationOne`, to point B: `locationTwo`. The MapView should display both points on the map, centered in between them.

I implemented a function to determine the center location as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559219/determining-midpoint-between-2-cooridinates), though I had to modify it to function in Swift. The function is called `findCenterPoint`.

Then, I set the mapView's region to an MKCoordinateRegion. This region is created like so: `let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, 2*distanceOne, 2*distanceTwo)`, and then the mapView's region is set like this: `mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)`

I multiply the distance by 2 so that we have a margin on the sides of the two locations (the annotation for locationOne, and locationTwo: the user location)

Here's the problem: If the two points are very far away, i.e. New York and somewhere in Australia (let's just say general Australia) the app can't display both points, because they don't fit on the mapView. So instead, only one pin is visible, because the other one is off the screen.

[Screenshots of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY00s.jpg)

I need both of those points to show up without scrolling around the map.

I also have a `degreesToRadians` function which is used in the code below.

**TL;DR**: My app's mapView isn't big enough to fit and display two far away points on the map, and it is already zoomed out to the max.

Here's the actual code:

```
var center = findCenterPoint(firstLocation.coordinate, locTwo: placemark.coordinate)
let earthRadius: Double = 6371000
distance = degreesToRadians(placemark.coordinate.latitude - firstLocation.coordinate.latitude)
lonDistance = degreesToRadians(placemark.coordinate.longitude - firstLocation.coordinate.longitude)

let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, earthRadius*distance, earthRadius*lonDistance)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
```

Comment: I don't think apple maps can do what you want. As you said, you already zoomed out to the max and your pins still don't fit. The result you are seeing on the screen is basically the best of what you can get from Apple maps. Apple maps cannot go beyond the maximum zoom level even if you set a region to be the whole world.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I think my best solution, in that case, is just to draw a polyline from point A to point B, and the user will know exactly where to scroll.